# Rails Mysql2::Error Table doesn't exist When create new migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

I wrote a migration with the following (create new table named `sources`):

```
class CreateSources < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sources do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false, default: ""

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And then I modified my existing model :

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :source, allow_blank: true, inclusion: { in: 
  Source.all.map{ |source| source.name } }
```

I want to add validation to the property's source to only allow source from `sources` table.

And then when I run the migration, I got the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'sources' doesn't exist: SELECT `sources`.* FROM `sources`
```

The problem is query of source table is occured when it hasn't been initialized yet.
Any tips on how I can get the migration to run?
This is run on production level. so I might can't drop all the migration and rearrange it.

Rails version 4.2.5
SQL version 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that your `Source.all.map{ |source| source.name }` is going to be executed when the `Property` class is being loaded. The `Source` class might not be properly initialized at that point and there might not be a proper database connection set up. Also, you'll only access `Source.all` once so you'd have to restart your app if you added a new `Source`.

Instead, validate by hand:

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :valid_source
private
  def valid_source
    return if(source.blank?)
    return if(Source.where(name: source).exists?)
    errors.add(:source, 'Unknown source') # Or whatever you want to say
  end
end
```

That way you're checking the `sources` table at the right time.

Also, I wouldn't expect the error you're seeing to occur in a migration. Perhaps you're using a model inside a migration, that is to be avoided.

As an aside, is there particular reason that you don't have `belongs_to :source` instead? Copying the name around like that is very error prone, using a reference (hopefully backed by a foreign key in the database) would be much safer.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now!! And also may I know how to check if I using model inside a migration? Seems like I don't do it, but it's occured.

Comment: To check the migrations you'd have to look at them by hand or search them. You might also want to check your initializers to see if they're up to anything.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you defined Source model? I hope so.
>
> Here the problem looks like the loading of Property class takes priority before
>   migration is run and hence the issue.

Comment: Yes I've defined it. And also Property migration is above Source migration.